# FTC theme suggestion: Reusing Information

Tags: steganography

Sometimes, I often particularly enjoy puzzles that reuse the same piece of information over and over. Essentially, it shares the elegance of a well constructed &lit, with whole text serving double-duty. Every word not only is used in entirety for the wordplay part, but the whole phrase could serve as a plausible definition too! Some more examples to follow:

- Encoding several different messages in the same piece of text, each one leading to the next by instructions.
- Neat meta structures sometimes allow for a set of answers to be used multiple times. The Mystery Hunt [has](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2011/puzzles/civilization/) [some](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2013/coinheist.com/sneakers/index.html) [examples](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2018/full/island/scifi.html).
- Extraction from the same ciphertext twice, using (ideally) two different ciphers - could be overambitious, but this theme is ambitious.
- Next, [a picture that has three interpretations](https://puzzle.cisra.com.au/2010/4A-Martial-Law.pdf) - although, this is close to puzzle sets, so try to seamlessly integrate the pieces.
- Chimera / double [grid-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzles ([see this link](https://nbpuzzles.wordpress.com/2014/06/08/double-puzzles/)). Each grid can work in multiple rulesets.
- Letters arranged in a grid. Extraction can appear in multiple ways - for example, [some letters could be a word search, others from a grille](http://www.mezzacotta.net/puzzle/2016/4A_AllAstir.pdf).

Note that simply reducing information and applying a recursive step isn't necessarily this - that would be using *newly* acquired data. Going back to square one is this theme's spirit! Then start over, with a fresh look, either by sheer inspiration or by explicit instruction. Have you noticed that this suggestion is itself a puzzle that self-illustrates this theme?

Comment: You‘ve nearly got me, but the rep amount gave it away — with 5k you surely know about meta 8–).  Nicely done though, in particular with the links and the content. +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First:

> the first letters of sentences spell "SEE SENTENCE LENGTH".

Then:

> the lengths of each sentence, when converted to letters (A=1, B=2...), spell **POWER OF SUGGESTION**.